# When using the Advanced Search API endpoint, how soon after the edit grace period is question data updated?

Tags: support, api, tags, search

I'm using the [Questions Advanced Search API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/advanced-search) to retrieve Stack Overflow questions with a specific tag that were created in the last 15 minutes.

I've written a script which runs every fifteen minutes and mostly retrieves the newly-created questions that I expect. However, I've noticed that the API doesn't reliably include questions that were created without my tag, but were then edited within the [grace period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/grace-period/info) to include my tag after creation.

How soon should I reasonably expect the Questions Advanced Search API endpoint to report these types of ninja-edited questions? I'm considering deliberately putting a 15-minute `fromdate`/`todate` delay in my script to give the API time to incorporate ninja edits, but can I safely use a smaller threshold instead?

Comment: When we do a tag clean-up it takes a minute or two until we don't get stale search results, so I assume a job runs every minute or so. I don't know if the API endpoints are as much live as the sites. Needs a dev to confirm.

Comment: Reporting back: a fifteen-minute delay has been working well for my script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr:** I think you can reduce the delay to 8-10 minutes. Grace period edits are available for 5 minutes after post creation and search results can be stale for a few minutes afterwards, especially during system maintenance or outages.

---

And now the details:

The advanced search API ultimately runs the same search as would happen if you searched the site manually. This means that grace period edits need to be re-indexed before they become available. There's also a bit of result caching happening on API's side, but I don't think it's relevant here.

Search index updates happen roughly every minute, so I think you could get away with 5 minutes for the grace period duration itself + a couple minutes for the reindex.

Indexing runs on its own schedule and system load could throw a wrench in as well, so you could potentially have an edit come in at the very end of the grace period that won't get picked up until a full minute + the time to actually update the index after that.

If the 15-minute delay is working well for you (which it sounds like it is) and is tolerable, I'd stick with that, but otherwise I think you could drop it down to 8 or 10 minutes without a loss of data outside of any unusual circumstances like an outage.